# Testing ngSwitch with Jasmine

Tags: angular, testing, karma-jasmine, ng-switch

I have a piece of HTML in my component:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="data.mode" class="data-mode">
    <span ngSwitchWhen="mode1">Mode 1 Activated</span>
    <span ngSwitchWhen="mode2">Mode 2 Activated</span>
</div>
```

and I want to test it through karma-jasmine. I can get the root element

```
const headerMode = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".data-mode"));
```

This returns the root node with 2 child elements but I cannot see which of the two is active.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

`By.css('.data-mode > span')` should return the activated element. Remember to call `fixture.detectChanges();` to force Angular's change detection to run and affect the elements in the test before hand.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const headerElement : HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
 expect(headerElement.querySelector('span').innerText).toBe('Mode 1 Activated');
```

This could be helpful to test ngSwitch .